# bash script: Appending bytes from an input file to a preexisting file at a given byte offset location

Tags: bash, shell

What I am trying to accomplish:
I have a file that I need to copy certain bytes from a certain location 
and append them to a file at a given location of that file.

I am thinking something along this lines:

```
xxd -s $startOffset -l $numBytes inFile | dd of=fileToModify seek=$location conv=notrunc
```

I have this as well but it will only work for appending at the beginning of a file.

```
read -p "Enter target file :> " targetFile
read -p "Enter source file to append at the end of target file :> " inputFile
dd if=$inputFile of=$targetFile oflag=append conv=notrunc
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want to push other content back, or overwrite it in-place? Standard UNIX filesystems *don't have any way* at the operating system level to insert content partway through a file without overwriting content later -- this is why your file formats that are intended for random-access insertion (by databases and the like) include use/free bitmaps, blocklists, and similar constructs.

Comment: *some* modern Linux filesystems allow inserting and deleting blocks midway through a file, but (1) it only operates on very specific files, and (2) it only operates on individual blocks, ie. you can only add block-sized chunks at block-boundary positions -- meaning maybe you can add a 4kb NUL page at a 4k boundary in the file, but you can't just add a line at some random position without having to rewrite everything after it to move such content back.

Comment: ...that's why your example in the question has to use `dd` to rewrite the entire rest of the file after the insertion point. If you want to do that yourself, that's fine, but it's not an "append" in the sense that writes to a file with `O_APPEND` don't need to write anything but the new content added to the end.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for taking the time to write back.
So basically I am trying to write another output file with them joined together and that is fine. I am just trying to find the best way to do it.

Comment: I would think of it as concatenating three sections into a new buffer and over writing the original file with the new buffer.  the new buffer would consist of: copy start of old file to insertion point. copy new material, copy old file from insertion point +1 till end.

Comment: @tomc That is correct. I am going to see what I can come up with tackling it that way.

Comment: Which version of `dd` do you have? Can we assume the GNU implementation?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, dd (coreutils) 8.28

Comment: Heh. I was asking wrt. whether `skip_bytes` was available, but you found it yourself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

contents of first file

```
$ cat first
fskasfdklsgdfksdjhgf sadjfsdjfhf
dsfghkasdfg sadfhsdfh hskdjfksdfgkfg
jhfksjdafhksdjfh


ksdjhfsdjfh
```

contents of sceond file

```
$ cat second
jfhasjdhfjskdhf dshfjsdfh3821349832749832]
87348732642364
]yfisdfhshf936494
sdfisdfsdfsa;dlf
9346934623984
```

contents of shell script

```
$ cat cppaste.sh
dd if=$1 of=$2 bs=1 count=$3 status=noxfer
dd if=$4 of=$2 bs=1 seek=$3 status=noxfer
finsize=$(stat -c%s $2)
dd if=$1 of=$2 bs=1 skip=$3 seek=$finsize oflag=append status=noxfer
```

executing shell script with proper arguments

```
$ bash cppaste.sh first  third 10 second
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
107+0 records in
107+0 records out
92+0 records in
92+0 records out
```

contents of the resultant file

```
$ cat third
fskasfdklsjfhasjdhfjskdhf dshfjsdfh3821349832749832]
87348732642364
]yfisdfhshf936494
sdfisdfsdfsa;dlf
9346934623984
gdfksdjhgf sadjfsdjfhf
dsfghkasdfg sadfhsdfh hskdjfksdfgkfg
jhfksjdafhksdjfh


ksdjhfsdjfh
```

Comment: Thank you! With a little tweaking I got it done!
I just had to add the functionality of the location of what bytes I wanted to copy and the number of bytes to copy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# copy certain bytes from a certain location 
file=$1
certainlocation=$2
certainbytes=$3
# Append them to a file at a given location of that file
givenlocation=$4

dd if=$file of=$file iflag=skip_bytes oflag=seek_bytes,append conv=notrunc skip=$certainlocation seek=$givenlocation count=1 bs=$certainbytes
```

Usage:

```
> printf "1\n2\n3\n4\n" > /tmp/1; ./1.sh /tmp/1 4 2 2; cat /tmp/1;
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
2 bytes copied, 0.000378992 s, 5.3 kB/s
1
2
3
4
3
```

Comment: You are on the right track. You are missing the second file (let's call it `file2`) to extract the bytes from, which is the bytes source, the number of bytes to extract from that e, which then need to be `file2` appended at a certain location of the original file (`file`).
As mentioned in the comment to my question, the bytes source from `file2` can not be appended per say to `file`, so a `tempFile` might be needed or using a buffer to put it all together and overwrite the file at the end or make an `outpuFile`

Comment: Just change `of=file2` in dd?

Comment: I did try that but it adds it to the end of the file instead of the given  location.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  dd if=inFile iflag=count_bytes count="$targetByteLocation" status=none
  cat -- "$fileToAppend"
  dd if=inFile iflag=skip_bytes skip="$targetByteLocation" status=none
} >outFile
```

Comment: That is awesome! 
However, how do I go about selecting the starting location and the number of bytes from `$fileToAppend`?

Comment: Ahh; didn't know you need that. Might replace the `cat` with a `dd` with `skip` and `count`, then.

Comment: BTW, if you only need to support a filesystem that supports reflinks, the first `dd` could be replaced with a `cp --reflink` and a `truncate` -- much faster that way, since everything before the block containing the insertion point could just be reused without needing to rewrite the bits on-disk.